# Does "I Couldn't Become a Hero, So I Reluctantly Decided to Get a Job." have an English dub?

Tags: yu-shibu

I saw a dubbed version of *I Couldn't Become a Hero, So I Reluctantly Decided to Get a Job.* back in the day but couldn't find it.

Does it have an English dub?

Answer (score 2):

It's licensed in the UK by MVM. [Their site](http://www.mvm-films.com/Title/Yusibu_[I_Couldn't_Become_A_Hero,_So_I_Reluctantly_Decided_To_Get_A_Job]) states,

> **Languages** Japanese
>   **Subtitles** English

Generally, when an anime is brought to the UK, if it's been dubbed, we get the dub. So, I would expect to see "**Languages** English, Japanese" here if it was translated.

According to [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=15565), it's stating DVD and Blu-ray sub for the US.

So it's possible that there has been a fandub? But if neither the US or the UK appear to have an English version release, I would assume there isn't an official English dub.